# Audit check is failed that a directory is not present

Tags: linux, bash, security, redhat

I have created a worker node in kubernetes and ran the audit check `6.2.7 Ensure root PATH Integrity` and it got failed saying that `/root/bin is not a directory`.

1. How does the `/root/bin` directory gets created usually in Rocky Linux Based machine?
2. Which service or which component is responsible for adding `/root/bin` directory to PATH env variable?
3. In the case `/root/bin` is not created, Do I need to remove it from the PATH env variable or I need to create `/root/bin` in the worker node with required permissions so that Audit test will pass.

It would be really helpful if someone helps me with this or clarifies the above points. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code contains at least a couple of anti-patterns, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".